# Problemas al actualizar BD con axios y vue en la vista

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

buen día, estoy desarrollando un proyecto en Laravel usando VUE, sin embargo presento el siguiente problema, tengo dos tablas una llamada Empleados Internos y otra llamada Clientes, quiero asignar de forma dinámica una empresa a los Empleados Internos para esto utilizo el v-if para mostrar texto y v-else para mostrar un select donde muestro los Clientes que tengo en la base de datos, me funciona correcto al momento de guardar en la Base de datos con Axios, hace la funcion sin problemas el problema es que en el view una vez que doy guardar me sigue mostrando la empresa o información anterior y no la actual, anexo el código del padre/hijo

SERVICIOS

```
<template>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center text-center">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2 class="text-primary">Empleados Registrados:</h2>
                <table class="table table-bordred table-striped ">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Telefono</th>
                        <th>Empresa</th>
                        <th>Acción</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                <empleadocomponente-component
                    v-for="(EmpleadosInterno, index) in EmpleadosInternos"
                    :key="EmpleadosInterno.id"
                    :EmpleadosInterno="EmpleadosInterno"
                    @update="updateEmpleadosInterno(index, ...arguments)"
                    @delete="deleteEmpleadosInterno(index)">
                </empleadocomponente-component>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            EmpleadosInternos: [],
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        axios.get('/EmpleadosInternos').then((response) => {
                this.EmpleadosInternos = response.data;
            },
        );
    },
    methods: {
        updateEmpleadosInterno(index, $event){
            this.EmpleadosInternos[index] = $event;
        },
        deleteEmpleadosInterno(index){
            this.EmpleadosInternos.splice(index, 1);
        }

    }
}
</script>
```

COMPONENTE

```
<template>
            <tr>
        <td> <h4 class="text-danger">{{EmpleadosInterno.completo}}</h4></td>
            <td><h4 class="text-black-50">{{EmpleadosInterno.telefono}}</h4></td>
            <td><h4 v-if="editEmpleado" class="text-black-50">{{EmpleadosInterno.empresa}}</h4>
                <select v-else class="form-control" id="Cliente" v-model="ClienteSeleccionado">
                    <option v-for="Cliente in Clientes"
                            :key="Cliente.id"
                            :value="Cliente">{{Cliente.nombreempresa}}</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a v-if="editEmpleado" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="onClickEdit()">
                    Asignar Empresa
                </a>
                <button v-else type="button" class="btn btn-success" v-on:click="onClickUpdate()">
                    Guardar Cambio
                </button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" v-on:click="deleteEmpleadosInterno(EmpleadosInterno.id)">
                    Eliminar Empleado
                </button>
            </td>
            </tr>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['EmpleadosInterno'],
    data() {
        return {
            ClienteSeleccionado: {},
            Clientes: [],
            csrf: document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),
            editEmpleado: true
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        axios.get('/Clientes').then((response) => {
                this.Clientes = response.data;
            },
        );
    },
    methods: {
        onClickEdit() {
            this.editEmpleado = false;
        },
        onClickUpdate() {
            const params = {
                nombreempresa: this.ClienteSeleccionado.nombreempresa
            }
            axios.put(`/EmpleadosInternos/${this.EmpleadosInterno.id}`, params).then((response) => {
                const EmpleadosInterno = response.data;
                const Cliente = response.data;
                this.$emit('update', EmpleadosInterno,Cliente);
            });
            this.editEmpleado = true;
        },
        deleteEmpleadosInterno(id) {
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Estas seguro?',
                text: "Esta acción es irreversible!",
                icon: 'Precuación',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                confirmButtonText: 'Si, eliminar!'
            }).then((result) => {

                if (result.value) {
                    //Send Request to server
                    axios.delete(`/EmpleadosInternos/${this.EmpleadosInterno.id}`).then(() => {
                        this.$emit('delete');
                    });
                }

            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obligar a que tu componente se refresque una vez termines la llamada de la API:

Agrega una key al componente que deseas actualilzar:

```
:key="componentKey"
```

Inicia un contador en tu data():

```
componentKey = 0
```

Una vez finalice la llamada de la Api actualiza la key del componente, esto hará que el componente se redibuje con los datos nuevos:

```
this.componentKey += 1;
```

Eso debería ser suficiente.

Por favor modifica tu pregunta, el código debe ir como texto.

Comment: Pues no =( no funciono, lo extraño es que si hago esto solamente con input type=text funciona correctamente, pero si lo hago con el select, no va...